# Windows 10 doesnt boot after install

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, boot, bios

I've run into a problem!
My computer is running somwhat old, but it was upgraded about 2015-2017 with diffrent parts. Today its running a MSI Mag Z390M Mortar motherboard with an intel i7 4790K and NVIDIA 970 card. I dont know if that info will be needed. I had 2 HDD drives but the one with the windows install was running slow and made the computer slow so I decided to take it out and format the other 4tb drive to run windows on that instead. I downloaded Win10 install on a usb and had my freshly formatted drive ready on Sata1, I've done windows installs before thinking it would be a pieace of cake.

To my problem. I come to the windows install, choose the windows 10 version of home, choose and advanced install and get to choose what partition to use. I've since then tried a lot of things but what I do is I run the bios in UEFI mode and change my drive to GPT using diskpart. That allows me to start the install and it runs to the first restart. Cool should work. Nope. I cant boot the drive after that. It doesnt come up as UEFI (I can see it in bios in legacy mode but not UEFI). So in UEFI mode I just come back to the same menu booted from the USB and in legacy the same thing. If I remove the USB and boot in legacy it just says "Put in boot drive and press a key to continue". I've then tried to run bcdboot /v x:\windows but that doesn't work. If I go into x:\windows using cmd and dir I see bunch of folders and files and it also says Volume in drive X is Boot.

What can I try to do any sugestion is a good one!:)

[Aomei](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9VWX.jpg)

Comment: What >I< would do first.. Either through a Linux Live USB stick or using the windows PE that is already on your boot media.  I myself keep a copy of [Hiren's Boot](https://www.hirensbootcd.org/) always handy on a spare USB stick for this sort of thing. (it isn't actually a CD)  Wipe the drive partitions totally.  Set UEFI or Legacy (sup to you) and boot back up off your boot media and setup your partitions from there.  Also, did you use the windows media creation tool to make your USB Windows boot media?

Comment: I'm trying this atm. I have used the windows media creation tool, should I use it? I need to redo it since I just loaded up AOMEI to try to remove the partition. I'll add a image of how that looked in the post.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Thank you for your answer. Idk what actually was diffrent but It seems to be working. I now have gotten past the first problem atleast, we will see if it will fully work

Comment: Awesome!  Glad it is working now.